# How to Create a script which generates index.html file for downloading android apk in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

A script written in command shell of Jenkins which redirects to a html page from where any user can download the apk file of the app.

Answer (score 0):

If we are dealing with static html file:

1. start with creating a basic static html file, add "a" element to it
   and link it "hard-coded" to your apk file. make sure that clicking
   on it will download the expected apk file.
2. Make sure that the Jenkins job own a variable populated with the apk's
   absolute location(aka path).
3. create a shell job and use the "sed" command to replace the previous
   hard-coded path with the current path (located in the variable we
   have set on step 2). You can use this answer as a guide line for
   this step:
   [Replacing HTML tag content using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189604/replacing-html-tag-content-using-sed)

good luck